# After latest Safari update, bank websites don't recognize my computer or autofilled name+pwd

Tags: safari, keychain

I'm running 10.13.6 on a late-2014 MBP.   After the latest Safari update (to 12.1), bank websites don't recognize my computer and/or autofilled user name+password.  Facebook says it doesn't recognize my browser, so it asked me to implement the second-half of two-factor authentication; I did this, and can now login to that site.

I don't have this issue logging into lower-security websites, like discussion forums, nor with sites for which I have a persistent login (i.e., those I can use without needing to re-login).

Is this standard behavior following a browser update, such that sites suspect I'm using a different computer or browser?  I don't recall this happening with previous Safari updates (but maybe it did and I simply don't remember).

Comment: I don't know quite what they changed, but something definitely did. However, for me 12.1 definitely fills & then 'auto-continues' far better than it has done in several years. It now actually recognises & will fill my bank web page, which it has refused to do for the past 5 years or so.

Comment: Did you change your user passwort in the meantime?

Comment: @George No, I haven't changed anything.

Answer (score 1):

Try launching Keychain Assistant.

Find the password for the site in the Passwords section.

Just double-check that the password is correct if you enter it manually.

I haven't had Safari/Keychain forget a password, especially a financial password, since I became a Mac convert in 2010, across many machines/devices and OS upgrades.

Comment: The problem isn't that Safari lost the passwords; they're still the same.  The problem is that, as a result of a browser update, high-security websites no longer allow me to use that name+password, since they associate that name+password with a specific computer and, as a result of the browser update, they don't think I'm using the same computer.  [Meaning I'll have to go through additional security checks before I can use the site with the new browser.]  My question is whether it's standard for a browser update to cause high-security websites to think I'm logging in from a different computer.

Comment: It's not "normal." I often set a password on my Mac, then log int to the same account a few days later from my iPhone or iPad. That's definitely NOT the same computer, but I've never had to do anything other than TouchID/FaceID to log onto the site unless it has 2FA.

Comment: Try a different browser; Chrome is getting very popular these days. I have no idea how your bank will react.